# Qt Application Disobeying Xmodmap

Tags: mouse, qt, scrolling

A long while ago, I created a `~/.Xmodmap` reversing the `4` and `5` to create "natural scrolling":

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12
```

I source `.Xmodmap` in `.xinitrc` in the standard fashion (`xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap &`).
This has worked for years without issues.

I just recently installed an application called [`cockatrice`](https://github.com/Daenyth/Cockatrice). I have no other issues with the program, except that, for some reason, when I scroll inside the program, my scrolling direction is not "natural" (i.e., it is as if my `.Xmodmap` is not being obeyed by only this application).

At first, I thought it was an issue with my Qt input module, but I realized that I have correctly declared `QT_IM_MODULE` to `xim` in my `.xinitrc`, and I've never had this issue with any other application.

Is this an application-specific issue, or is this Qt-specific? What should I try to further troubleshoot this (or solve it)?

Attempting to set this universally through `xinput` fails:

```
$ xinput list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
# unneeded information regarding my keyboard
$ xinput set-prop 2 "Evdev Scrolling Distance" -1 -1 -1
property 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be Qt specific (from trying in Qt Assistant).
I think it is because Qt uses only the scrolling distance for its wheel events.

Instead of using xmodmap here, you can set your scrolling distance to negative values.

You can set it through a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, for a mouse managed by evdev :

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Reverse Scrolling"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "-1"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-1"
        Option "DialDelta" "-1"
EndSection
```

Or you can try with `xinput` first :

`xinput set-prop <your device id> "Evdev Scrolling Distance" -1 -1 -1`

(To get the device id : `xinput list`)

The properties are listed with the actual device. Here `xinput list-props 12` should list the properties of the touchpad. As it is a synaptics touchpad, from [this man page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html) the property should be :

`xinput set-prop <touchpad id> "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" -1 -1` (Only two values, vertical and horizontal edges.)

For the rule in the configuration file, it should work with `MatchIsTouchpad` :

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Natural Scrolling"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "-1"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-1"
EndSection
```

Comment: I assume using this solution would mean no longer using `xmodmap` and then hoping that this would function universally? (Not a bad thing necessarily, just clarifying.)

Comment: @HalosGhost Yes it should work everywhere. And xmodmap shouldn't be used at the same time, otherwise the scrolling is reversed twice for some apps ..

Comment: I finally got around to testing this, but the xorg conf file has no effect, and testing through `xinput` produces the error I mention in the edit of the OP.

Comment: @HalosGhost Updated. For a synaptics touchpad the property seem to be "Synaptics Scrolling Distance".

Comment: The updated configuration has the desired effect but creates a side-effect of having incredibly jumpy scrolling.

Comment: A quick note: remember to remove `~/.Xmodmap` file before restarting X. Running `xmodmap -e` to undo the setting in `~/.Xmodmap` will not help if you forgot to delete `~/.Xmodmap` before restarting X.

Answer (score 1):

I want to supplement @Leiaz's answer.
In my case, I'm using **Logitech M325**.
`$ xinput`

> ⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
>   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
>   ⎜   ↳ HID 04b4:0823                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
>   ⎜   ↳ Logitech M325                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
>   ⎜   ↳ Logitech M185/M225                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

`$ xinput list-props 12`

> Device 'Logitech M325':
>           Device Enabled (152):   1
>           Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
>           libinput Accel Speed (286):     0.000000
>           libinput Accel Speed Default (287):     0.000000
>           libinput Accel Profiles Available (288):        1, 1
>           libinput Accel Profile Enabled (289):   1, 0
>           libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (290):   1, 0
>           **libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (291):       0**
>           libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (292):       0
>           libinput Send Events Modes Available (271):     1, 0
>           libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):        0, 0
>           libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):        0, 0
>           libinput Left Handed Enabled (293):     0
>           libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (294):     0
>           libinput Scroll Methods Available (295):        0, 0, 1
>           libinput Scroll Method Enabled (296):   0, 0, 0
>           libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (297):   0, 0, 0
>           libinput Button Scrolling Button (298): 2
>           libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (299): 2
>           libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (300):        0
>           libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (301):        0
>           Device Node (274):      "/dev/input/event16"
>           Device Product ID (275):        1133, 16394
>           libinput Drag Lock Buttons (302):       
>           libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (303):       1

Note that there is a "Natural Scrolling Enabled (291)" property, change it to "1", the direction of your mouse wheel will be inverse.
`$ xinput set-prop 12 291 1`

If you want to wrap the procedure in a shell script, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

dev_id=$(xinput | sed -n '/Logitech M325/{s/^.*Logitech M325\s\+id=\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/;p;}')

if [[ -z "$dev_id" ]];then
  exit 1
fi

nse_id=$(xinput list-props "$dev_id" | sed -n '/Natural Scrolling Enabled ([0-9]\+)/{s/^.*Natural Scrolling Enabled (\([0-9]\+\)).*/\1/;p;}')

if [[ -z "$nse_id" ]];then
  exit 1
fi

xinput set-prop "$dev_id" "$nse_id" 1
xinput list-props "$dev_id" | grep -o "Natural Scrolling Enabled ($nse_id):\s\+[0-9]"
```

Change "Logitech M325" to the device name of your own one.